# How to sort a list of lists based on length of inner list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested

I want to sort a list of lists based on the length of the second item in the sublists, like this:

Input:

```
list = [['A', '1234', 'X'],['B', '12', 'X'],['C', '12345', 'X'],['D', '123', 'X']]
```

Output:

```
list = [['C', '12345', 'X'],['A', '1234', 'X'],['D', '123', 'X'],['B', '12', 'X']]
```

What i have so far is:

```
list = sorted(list, key=len, reverse=True)
```

But I'm not sure how to get it to look at length of on *specific item* in the lists. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't name your variable `list` as this is a python built in function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `sort` or `sorted` with custom key.

**Ex:**

```
data = [['A', '1234', 'X'],['B', '12', 'X'],['C', '12345', 'X'],['D', '123', 'X']]
data.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

---

or `sorted`

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

---

```
print(data)
```

Comment: @ScottHunter of course it can, but it produces a new list. So if you want to update the existing one, creating a new one and assigning it to the old one (`sorted`-solution)  is wasteful compared to updating the old one in place (`.sort`-solution).

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you very much Rakesh!

If you dont mind, I'll sneak in another related question:
In the example above let's say the third item in a integer. How would i go about sorting the list:
1) By integer (higher value first)
2) If the same integer then by your solution above.

i.e ['B', '12', '1'] would get sorted before ['A', '123', '0']

No worries at all if you don't have the time to answer me!  Thanks again

Comment: @Fred_Alb looks like you need `key=lambda x: int(x[2])`?

Comment: @Rakesh You did it again! Thanks!       
     key=lambda x: (int(x[2]), len(x[1])), reverse=True)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
data = [['A', '1234', 'X'],['B', '12', 'X'],['C', '12345', 'X'],['D', '123', 'X']]

out = sorted(data, key=lambda item: len(item[1]), reverse=True)

print(out)
#[['C', '12345', 'X'], ['A', '1234', 'X'], ['D', '123', 'X'], ['B', '12', 'X']]
```

Note that you shouldn't name your list `list`, as this would shadow the name of the builtin function and lead to problems later...